# Untyped external table result

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm running a simple query on an external table.
Even that the external table has typed columns, the results is always kinda untyped.

[image]

This makes joins on this table not working correct.

[image]

Even if I try to force a type column, it is untyped after.

[image]

I would expect a result like this:

```
"DeviceID": 1702843,
"DeviceUniqueIdentifier": "inverter::92092SL40002M",
"DeviceType": "Inverter",
"DeviceName": "scb",
"DataSourceID": 80739,
"DataSourceName": "scb",
"SiteID": 57492,
"SiteName": "something",
"Test": "test"
```

===== Update related to comment from yifats ==================

Here the related join query:

```
external_table('DeviceMapping')
| where SiteID == 57492
| extend DeviceIdLeft = tostring(DeviceID)
| join kind= fullouter    
( 
    DeviceData
    | extend DeviceIdRight = DeviceId
 ) on $left.DeviceIdLeft == $right.DeviceIdRight
```

Comment: All columns are strongly typed (you can use `getschema` operator to find the schema of a query). The UX displays it without the quotes. You haven't shared the query you're using for the join, but it looks like the left hand of DeviceId in it is numeric (like in the external table definition) while the right side is a string and this is why the join isn't matching. What are you using on the right side of the join? Is DeviceId numeric or string there?

Comment: @yifats thanks for your answer. I added the query into the initial question. I did consider the type mismatch within the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data that was insgested was using from string format.

Wrong syntax:

```
.ingest inline into table [DeviceDataIngestion] <|
1702848,2023-01-01 10:00:00,'ac_current',10
2211260,2023-01-01 11:00:00,'ac_current',10
```

Correct syntax:

```
.ingest inline into table [DeviceDataIngestion] <|
1702848,2023-01-01 10:00:00,"ac_current",10
2211260,2023-01-01 11:00:00,"ac_current",10
```

String needs to be escaped with `"` not `'`.